# Total number of earned points in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

What is the total number of earned points (by all of the users) in Stack Overflow?

Comment: As of now: 523902022

Comment: @ryanyuyu How'd you get that? "confused"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According the to most recent data (Apr 26, 2015 at 6:43 UTC) in the data explorer and this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309274/sum-of-reputation),

Total rep for all users is **523,902,022**

Comment: Which does not include any reputation lost to 1. Downvoting answers, or questions before the change 2. Getting downvoted. 3. Penalties for offensive/spam posts 4. Deleted users. 5. Rep lost to unawarded / some auto-awarded bounties. 6. All but one point belonging to each suspended user. 7. Anything earned since the last data dump. Probably some others. Whether those are in any way relevant...

Comment: Nope it doesn't, but it does answer total rep "earned".  If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Deduplicator - So what you are saying is that this is 99.99% accurate.

Comment: @TravisJ: *Yes.*

Comment: It's a big number... let's just say it's 679 Jon Skeets. That's easier to read ;-)